# Add additional info in authetication reply

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security, spring-security-rest

Working on a REST API application using Grails 3.3.5 and Spring-security-rest 2.0.0-RC1.

When I log in using /api/login I got correctly this as result:

```
{
    "username": "name.surname@acme.com",
    "roles": [
        "ROLE_USER"
    ],
    "access_token": "qgsbpk05jfrbf33xx08m8r4govkg53d1"
}
```

I'd like to add other information in the response, like name and surname of the user. Thanks

**UPDATE**
Thanks to Evgeny that points me in the right direction and reading the manual I implement also a UserDetailsService.
From the manual:

> If you want to render additional information in your JSON response,
>   you have to:
>
> ```
> Configure an alternative userDetailsService bean that retrieves the additional information you want, and put it in a principal object.
>
> Configure an alternative accessTokenJsonRenderer that reads that information from the restAuthenticationToken.principal object.
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override **accessTokenJsonRenderer** bean

1. Create class:

> ```
> class MyRestAuthTokenJsonRenderer implements AccessTokenJsonRenderer {
>     @Override
>     String generateJson(AccessToken accessToken){
>         // create response, see DefaultAccessTokenJsonRenderer.groovy from https://github.com/alvarosanchez/grails-spring-security-rest
>         return your_formatted_json_response
>     }
> }
> ```

2. override bean in resources.groovy

> ```
> beans = {
>    accessTokenJsonRenderer(MyRestAuthTokenJsonRenderer)
> }
> ```

Comment: isn't accessTokenJsonRenderer instead of restAuthenticationTokenJsonRenderer?